# How do I upgrade to the latest version of Shotwell?

Tags: 10.10, shotwell, gstreamer

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, and am trying to upgrade Shotwell to the latest version (0.11.1). I've been trying to follow the instructions on [the Shotwell installation page](http://yorba.org/shotwell/install/) for building from source but I have run into a problem.

When I run `make`, I get the following message:

```
Requested 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10 >= 0.10.32' but version of GStreamer Base Utils Library is 0.10.30
make: *** [pkgcheck] Error 1
```

It seems like the problem is that I need a newer version of GStreamer, but I'm not sure. What should I do from this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [PPA on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/shotwell) which the maintainer supports for new shotwell releases for both Lucid and Maverick.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/shotwell
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

As you can see - it does involve upgrading to the latest gstreamer from the gstreamer developers themselves.

So you could have two choices:

1. Install just that gstreamer PPA and then compile your shotwell code from source or...
2. Install both PPA's and have the "almost" newest version of Shotwell available!

As for all PPA's - they can make your system unstable, so have a backup before installing - or use `ppa-purge` to remove misbehaving PPAs.