# Black screen where once there was a login screen after installing Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I was on my 10.04 machine this evening when I decided to run an update.  The packages were from the flexiondotorg ppa which is for backports of Shotwell.  Shotwell had an update 2days ago so I was surprised to see more.  They were for libglib2.0 and libc-bin.  After logging out I got the blank screen.  Could these have knackered the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have used this [AU question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60846/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-shotwell).

The easiest way to confirm this is to either boot into recovery mode or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for a TTY

Then run a ppa-purge on the type PPAs

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:flexiondotorg/shotwell
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
```

This will downgrade gstreamer and shotwell back to the standard repository versions.

Once done, reboot.

If you still have a black-screen, then it is not the shotwell/gstreamer PPAs that have caused your black-screen issue.

Comment: Bravo fossfreedom :-* . Had to get a ppa for lucid to get ppa-purge. I purged flexiondotorg and rebooted and the issue is fixed. Thank you

Comment: excellent - dont forget to file a bug report on flexiondotorg launchpad PPA so that the maintainer is aware and can provide you a fix in the (hopefully) near future.

Comment: i emailed the developer. can;t figure out how to file a bug on flexioindotorg ppa. will try again on the morrow.

Comment: ah, the instructions are on the ubuntu wiki